# Node Sass failing to install

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cmd, jsx, node-sass

I tried installing Node sass in my react app by running

> npm install node-sass

It failed with an error

> Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.

I've tried

- Removing the node-modules
- Removing the package-lock.json
- Runing "npm install"

Still didn't work.

Comment: Well, have you tried to upgrade to version 7 or higher??

Comment: Yes, I have. Still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, my node version is not updated.

I had to unistall my Node app from the control panel,
Download the latest version,
and then reinstall.

Then I re ran my 'npm install' for the node modules.

This worked for me.